# Make jQuery dropdown toggle when click away?

Tags: jquery

I am using a jQuery drop down and I want the box to toggle when you click off the box

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('li.menu_head').mouseenter(function () {
    $('div.newsadviceDrop').slideToggle('medium');
  });
});
```

Can you help me?

Comment: When you 'click' off of it, or just when the mouse leaves?

Answer (score 3):

I had to do something similar and the way I worked it out was to do something like

```
$('div.newsadviceDrop').click(function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});
$(document).click(function() {
    ('div.newsadviceDrop').slideToggle('medium');
});
```

Basically, you need to toggle the menu if any other place is clicked, but if the actual location is clicked, you need to prevent the event from bubbling up to perform a toggle.

Comment: This looks like it should work but it doesn't. Is what you wrote something to be added to my code or rewritten?

Comment: This is definitely something to be rewritten. I did it quickly based off of what I remembered from when I tried to implement something similar. I wanted to express the basic idea behind what I did.

Comment: Come to think of it I think it may need to be
    $(body).click(function());
Also, My syntax is bad on the code above. I'll fix it. Edit: The code above should work now, but I'm still not sure if it should be body or document.